# How to use the copy command to copy data from a json file to a Postgres table?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "plane": {
        "type":"Boeing",
                "weight":"heavy"
    }
}
```

How would I use the copy command to take this data and insert it into one of my postgres tables?

I've tried: copy table_name from file_path; but it does not seem to work

Comment: 1) It won't, per [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) is for CSV files only. 2) This `{ "plane": { "type":"Boeing", "weight":"heavy" } }` is a nested structure and CSV is a flat structure.

Comment: You should use formatting to set off your example from your prose, and do so in a way which preserves whitespace.

Comment: Your example should include at least two records.  Otherwise, we don't know how the records are separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this will be a multistep process.

1. Convert JSON to a newline delimited json (NDJSON)
2. Import the NDJSON to a temp table:

   - `\COPY temp (data) FROM 'my_data.json';`
   - This will allow for a queryable dataset.
3. Move temp data to desired table:

   - Look here for JSON functions and operations in PGSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html
4. Delete temp table

I pulled these details from this guide: https://konbert.com/blog/import-json-into-postgres-using-copy

Hope this helps!